# Single function to handle fade in/out

Tags: jquery, html, timer, replace, fade

I have many pages (divs) on a page, and I need a single function to fade in/out these pages. So far I have:

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class="menulink">
    <a href="#page2" class="link" onclick="return false">
        ABOUT EVENT
    </a>
    </div>

    <div class="menulink">
    <a href="#page3" class="link" onclick="return false">
        OTHER EVENTS
    </a>
    </div>

    ... <!--LOTS OF OTHER LINKS-->
    ...

    <div class="pagecontainer">


    <div id="homepage">
        content
    </div>

    <div id="page2">
        content
    </div>

    ...<!--LOTS OF OTHER DIVS-->

    </div>

</body>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        e.preventDefault();

        $('.link').on('click', function(e){
            var targetpage = $($(this).attr("href"));
            $('.pagecontainer>div').fadeOut(function() {
                $(targetpage).show();
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.pagecontainer {
overflow:hidden;
width:90%;
min-width:800px;
padding:50px 0;
min-height:450px;
}

.pagecontainer>div{
display: none;
padding-left:50px;
padding-right:50px;
position:relative;
}

#menu {
display:none;
width:90%;
height:40px;
margin:auto;
}
```

This works in fading various pages in/out, however what it does is show the target page FIRST, and then fade the previous page out. This causes the target page to be displayed in some random position to wait for the previous to fade out, then the target page will "jump" to the correct position.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try this -> http://jsfiddle.net/u2cYK/

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by waiting for the eventqueue to be done by using jQuery's [`promise`()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [`done()`](http://api.jquery.com/done/) methods.

```
 $('.pagecontainer>div').fadeOut(500).promise().done(function() {
      $(targetpage).fadeIn(500);
 });
```

This will first fadeout all the pages, then when it's done, fadeIn the target.